# how to find the divs specific Nth siblings of child divs positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i create new hours calendar. as per the **IMAGE1** when user click on any of div that dynamic Span was created up to 8 hours.
i.e. if click on 00:00 its design up to 08:00 hours

so my question is how to get that specific siblings 8th divs child position.

Or any other way please suggest me.

```
$(this).eq(+8).attr("id");
```

**IMAGE1**
[image]

Table Design Code when ajax return Success:

```
$(r.emp_nm).each(function (index) {
                tabelBody += "<tr><td style='width:10%'><div class='col-xs-3 col-md-3 on-break-tab'>" + this.fname.charAt(0) + this.lname.charAt(0) + "</div>" + this.fname + ' ' + this.lname + " </td>";
                for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                    var tabelsubBody = "";
                    var p = 15;
                    var t_id = r.hours[i];
                    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        tabelsubBody += "<div style='float:left; width:25%;height:inherit;'  class='Dropablesub_td' data-employeID='" + this.id + "' data-date='" + t_id + "' id='" + t_id + "_" + this.id + "_" + j + "'></div>";
                    }
                    if (i === 23) {
                        tabelBody += "<td style='width:12.5%' class='Dropabletd' data-employeID='" + this.id + "' data-date='" + t_id + "' id='" + t_id + "_" + this.id + "'>" + tabelsubBody + "</td></tr>";
                    } else {
                        tabelBody += "<td style='width:12.5%' class='Dropabletd'  data-employeID='" + this.id + "' data-date='" + t_id + "' id='" + t_id + "_" + this.id + "'>" + tabelsubBody + "</td>";
                    }
                }

            });
            $("#tabelBody").html(tabelBody);
            $("#tdDate").html(r.today);
            $("#SelectDate").val(r.today);
            $("#currentSelect").val("Days");

            Events();
```

And Events() is :

```
 function Events() {

    $("body").on("click", ".Dropablesub_td", function () {
        var hidid = $(this).attr("id");
        var Myleft = $(this).position().left;
        var Mytop = $(this).position().top;
        alert($(this).eq(+8).attr("id"));
        $(this).append("<span id='" + hidid + "'  class='divId label label-success ui-widget-content filediv unselectable' >ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<span>");
        $(this).children(
                ).css({zIndex: 999, position: "absolute", top: Mytop, left: Myleft, width: '40%', display: "block", border: "#808080 solid 2px", color: "black", background: "#00CEB4"});
    });
}
```

Comment: You have to add some HTML code inside your question, it is not clear what you want, can't help.

Comment: Okay Sir, just create dynamic tbody, i can share code @skbaljic

Comment: thanks for guidance @Satpal Sir

Comment: @Satpal It is Not Working correctly.
not getting proper siblings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired element using `.index()` of current element and then using `.eq()` to target the next element.

Here in the snippet I have created a pseudo code for demonstration

```js
$(document).on("click", ".dropabletd", function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var tds = tr.find('td');
  var index = tds.index(this);
  var sibling = tds.eq(index + 8);
  console.log($(this).attr('id'), sibling.attr('id'));
});

createTable();

function createTable() {
  var tabelBody = ""
  for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
    tabelBody += "<td class='dropabletd' id='id" + i + "'>" + i + "</td>";
  }
  $("table tr").html(tabelBody);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for helping me bro, but when i was click on 1st parents child at that time need to check all that conditions like that flow as.
child => parents => siblings parents=> child
i.e if i was click on 00:45 hours than i get 8:45 hours child div that are in 8 hour parent div